# Need to collect full HTML paragraph text but <br /> limits results

Tags: python, html, lxml, elementtree

I'm scraping comments from a blog site using lxml.

I've found the paragraph I want to collect but results returned are truncated to text prior to first instance of:

```
<br />
```

here's a snip of the html...

```
                                    <p>Great Post.<br />
Really Helpful for us.<br />
thank you</p>
```

here is my path to the target paragraph:

```
root[1][2][0][0][0][6][0][0][0][1][3].text
```

what gets returned is:

```
>>> 'Great Post.'
```

any ideas how I can get the full text from this paragraph?

Comment: You should post more of the HTML. Additionally, they way you are accessing that element is risky. Given the huge list of indexes any small change in the DOM will throw things off.

Comment: the entire HTML can be found at: [link](view-source:http://www.worldofwanderlust.com/access-money-overseas-need-board-plane/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should be using `lxml.html` to parse HTML (not `lxml.etree`). Then, once you locate the element, use `.text_content()` method to get the complete "text" of an element including children texts.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance to use lxml.html-   worked like a charm